# How to retrieve the port information from the header in PHP (Code igniter)?

Tags: php, codeigniter, header, port, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to get the port information from the header request in PHP.  Code Igniter to be specific?

I tried doing:

```
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
```

Port Information is not available.

We are using an Elastic Beanstalk from Amazon as a server.  We were told that:
There is a header sent from the EC2 load balancer called "X-Forwarded-Proto" which fluctuates depending on if we are http or https.

If I try to do:

```
    $headers = apache_request_headers(); 
    $port = $headers["X-Forwarded-Port"]; 
    echo "X-Forwarded-Port : " . $port;
```

This gives me an 
ERROR - 2012-10-19 00:48:05 --> Severity: Notice --> Undefined index: X-Forwarded-Port

I would appreciate any thoughts on how to get the PORT information from the headers!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do a print_r for $_SERVER and see what's coming in

Answer (score 2):

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'] for remote port
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] for server port
```